# std::move a variable that is going to be overwritten

Tags: c++, stdmove

I ran up on some [code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
constexpr // since C++20
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = std::move(init) + *first; // std::move since C++20
    }
    return init;
}
```

I have a question. Why would we have to use std::move on `init` even if `init` is `int`?

Comment: you don't "have to" for any type.

Comment: The point is in generic code you don't *know* what `T` will be.  It could be `int`, or it could be `MyBigFatObject`.

Comment: The only advantage I see here is if there is a `T operator+(T&&, const T&)` which would be surprising. But I see that there is a note that `std::move` was added in C++20 so there is probably an upcoming change to the language which would make that case more common. I'm curious why `init += *first` wouldn't be used intead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: There's a huge advantage if `init` is a string with a large enough buffer, as this changes from `N` allocations/copies to 0.  Also, `std::move` was added in C++11.

Comment: @MooingDuck `std::move` was added *to that function* in C++20. It's noted in the linked example. And using `init += *first` would have the same benefit. Though I see that `operator+` with rvalue reference does exist for `std::string`, which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, moving an `int` is no different from copying it.

Here, `std::move` only becomes useful only if `T`'s overloaded `operator+` behaves differently for lvalues and rvalues.

I've never heard of such classes, but I guess it could be useful for dynamic arrays that overload `+` in a clever way:

```
struct Vec
{
    std::vector<int> elems;
};

// Returns a completely new vector.
Vec operator+(const Vec &a, const Vec &b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    Vec ret(a.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        ret.elems[i] = a.elems[i] + b.elems[i];
    return ret;
}
// Reuses storage of `a`.
Vec operator+(Vec &&a, const Vec &b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        a.elems[i] += b.elems[i];
    return std::move(a);
}
// Reuses storage of `b`.
Vec operator+(const Vec &a, Vec &&b)
{
    return std::move(b) + a;
}
// Reuses storage of `a`.
Vec operator+(Vec &&a, Vec &&b)
{
    return std::move(a) + b;
}
```

**Edit:** apparently `std::string` does a similar thing: its `+` reuses storage of one of the operands, if possible. (Thanks @FrançoisAndrieux and @Artyer.)

Comment: [`std::operator+(std::string&&, const std::string&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) exists. In general, I would assume it would be implemented as `return std::move(lhs += rhs)`

Answer (score 3):

There's no "need," per se, to use `std::move` in the case where `T` is `int`. However, since we can think of `std::move` as basically meaning "please cast this expression to an rvalue," a good compiler should not introduce any overhead when compiling this code in the case where `T` is an `int`. So in that sense, this code will *definitely* improve performance for some types `T`, and it's *unlikely* to hurt performance on types for which moving is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

We don't "have" to `std::move` `init`. We (or rather, the standard library in this instance) do it because moving can be more efficient than copying for some types.

> even if init is int?

`init` is not necessarily `int`. It is `T`, which is a template type argument.

Comment: `std::move` only helps if you have `T operator+(T&&, const T&)` which I have never encountered before. Is there anything like that in the standard library, or is there another reason for it that I don't see? Otherwise, while it isn't wrong, it seems unlikely to ever be relevant. Using `init += *first` seems more likely to do the right thing than `init = std::move(init) + *first;` to me.

Comment: But how is it going under the hood? Could you explain please?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: `std::string` has the overload. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for the example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `std::accumulate` is implemented in terms of `operator+`, so it can't use `+=`

Comment: @Artyer In retrospect that seems obvious. Thank you for the clarifiation.